# I don't understand functioning of iterating variables (i,j) in this code

Tags: python, web-scraping

In following code two iteration variable(i,j in code) are used and print one variable in first sentence of loop and second iterating variable use in those variable..this is used for extracting data from website....I am a beginner in python and did,t understand this code...can someone explain please

```py
for j,i in enumerate(data):
       print(j)
       link = (i.a['href'])
       image = (i.img['data-src'])
       text = (i.find(class_="gallery-caption-content").text)
       d = {'link':link,'image':image,'text':text}
       print(d)
```

Comment: `enumerate` returns the index an item, in this case `i`, and the actual item, in this case `j`, of a iterable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enumerate is a built-in function of Python. It allows us to loop over something and have an automatic counter. Here is an example:

```py
my_list = ['apple', 'banana', 'grapes', 'pear']
for counter, value in enumerate(my_list):
    print counter, value

# Output:
# 0 apple
# 1 banana
# 2 grapes
# 3 pear
```

source: [Python Enumerate Documentation](https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/enumerate.html)
In your example, **j** is used only for print, probably it is for debuging

Comment: but in the output numbering came to each dictionary set not to key in the dictionary then why did there is i iterating variable used in every variable created in for loop

Comment: Because the iterating variable returned from enumerable is a index like and the dictionary key not is indexed like a number

Comment: Thanks Matheus but still i have this doubt... why did there is  " i "  iterating variable used in every variable created in for loop?